# Combining Nested Objects in a JSON Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I have a JSON array with nested objects, as below:

```
var cData = [{
    "name": "Jack Doe",
    "desc": "Jack",
    "values": [{
        "id": "615",
        "subject": "Physics",
        "Grade": "B"
    }, {
        "id": "616",
        "subject": "Chemistry",
        "Grade": "A"
    }]
},
{
    "name": "Jane Doe",
    "desc": "Jane",
    "values": [{
        "id": "715",
        "subject": "Maths",
        "Grade": "A+"
    }]
},
{
    "name": "Jack Doe",
    "desc": "Jack",
    "values": [{
        "id": "617",
        "subject": "Maths",
        "Grade": "A"
    }]
},
{
    "name": "Jane Doe",
    "desc": "Jane",
    "values": [{
        "id": "716",
        "subject": "Physics",
        "Grade": "B"
    }]
}]
```

I want to consolidate objects in above array to

```
var cData = [{
    "name": "Jack Doe",
        "desc": "Jack",
        "values": [{
        "id": "615",
            "subject": "Physics",
            "Grade": "B"
    }, {
        "id": "616",
            "subject": "Chemistry",
            "Grade": "A"
    }, {
        "id": "617",
            "subject": "Maths",
            "Grade": "A"
    }]
},

{
    "name": "Jane Doe",
        "desc": "Jane",
        "values": [{
        "id": "715",
            "subject": "Maths",
            "Grade": "A+"
    }, {
        "id": "716",
            "subject": "Physics",
            "Grade": "B"
    }]
}]
```

If any one has any suggestions for me it'd be really great! jQuery methods are also welcome.

Comment: what have you tried so far? also are you looking to merge the records based on the name field or the description field?  how should differences in the other field be handled?

Comment: If I am not wrong you want to merge object in reference to same "name"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write function to merge array of objects under key and then get map values.
Here it is:

Merge function:

```
function mergeArray(array) {
    var merged = {};
    $.each(array, function() {
        var item = this;
        // Use name as a key
        if (typeof merged[item.name] != 'undefined') {
            // merge values array
            $.merge(merged[item.name].values, item.values);
        }
        else {
            merged[item.name] = item;
       }
    });
    // get values from { key1: value1, key2: value2, ... } object
    return getObjectValues(merged);
}
```

Getting values from object:

```
function getObjectValues(obj) {
    var values = [];
    $.each(obj, function(key,valueObj){
        values.push(valueObj);
    });
    return values;
}
```

Here is [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7v2Cs/1/).

Comment: great, working perfectly fine when I did included this in my program . I was working on this last two days could not able to figureout. Thank you very much for quick solution.