# How can I merge two JSON objects, appending one set of data as a sub-object of another set of data?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm working on building out a JSON object for usage with the DataTables child row option in order to show lane-rates for various customers. I have collected this data into JSON objects.

I've been messing with this js fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/7v2Cs/1/) to try and merge the objects, but haven't had much success as they use different formats. (based on this question: [Combining Nested Objects in a JSON Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948009/combining-nested-objects-in-a-json-array))

Data is formatted as such:

```
  var cData = 
  [
     {
        "customer_name":"Company1",
        "type_of_shipment":"F",
        "pickup_city":"MARTINSBURG",
        "pickup_state":"WV",
        "consignee_city":"BALL GROUND",
        "consignee_state":"GA",
        "AVG( proj_revenue )":"1683.333333",
        "AVG( proj_gross_profit )":"216.666667",
        "COUNT( pro_num )":3
     },
     {
        "customer_name":"Company2",
        "type_of_shipment":"V",
        "pickup_city":"ALLENTOWN",
        "pickup_state":"PA",
        "consignee_city":"ROBBINSVILLE",
        "consignee_state":"NJ",
        "AVG( proj_revenue )":"572.320000",
        "AVG( proj_gross_profit )":"222.320000",
        "COUNT( pro_num )":2
     },
     {
        "customer_name":"Company2",
        "type_of_shipment":"V",
        "pickup_city":"BUENA PARK",
        "pickup_state":"CA",
        "consignee_city":"NEWARK",
        "consignee_state":"CA",
        "AVG( proj_revenue )":"1132.820000",
        "AVG( proj_gross_profit )":"-217.180000",
        "COUNT( pro_num )":1
     },
     {
        "customer_name":"Company3",
        "type_of_shipment":"V",
        "pickup_city":"BENSENVILLE",
        "pickup_state":"IL",
        "consignee_city":"STAUNTON",
        "consignee_state":"VA",
        "AVG( proj_revenue )":"3725.000000",
        "AVG( proj_gross_profit )":"1025.000000",
        "COUNT( pro_num )":2
     }
  ]

  var cData2 = [
     {
        "customer":"Company1",
        "shipments1":1,
        "profit1":"0.00",
        "gp_percent1":"0.0000",
        "agp1":"0.00"
     },
     {
        "customer":"Company2",
        "shipments1":0,
        "profit1":"0.00",
        "gp_percent1":"0.0000",
        "agp1":"0.00"

     },
     {
        "customer":"Company3",
        "shipments1":0,
        "profit1":"0.00",
        "gp_percent1":"0.0000",
        "agp1":"0.00"
     }
  ]
```

The idea is to have the data formatted like this:

```
  var cDataFinal = 
  [
     {
        "customer":"Company1",
        "shipments1":1,
        "profit1":"0.00",
        "gp_percent1":"0.0000",
        "agp1":"0.00",
        "lanes":[
        {
              "customer_name":"Company1",
              "type_of_shipment":"F",
              "pickup_city":"MARTINSBURG",
              "pickup_state":"WV",
              "consignee_city":"BALL GROUND",
              "consignee_state":"GA",
              "AVG( proj_revenue )":"1683.333333",
              "AVG( proj_gross_profit )":"216.666667",
              "COUNT( pro_num )":3
        }]
     },
     {
        "customer":"Company2",
        "shipments1":0,
        "profit1":"0.00",
        "gp_percent1":"0.0000",
        "agp1":"0.00",
        "lanes":[
        {
              "customer_name":"Company2",
              "type_of_shipment":"V",
              "pickup_city":"ALLENTOWN",
              "pickup_state":"PA",
              "consignee_city":"ROBBINSVILLE",
              "consignee_state":"NJ",
              "AVG( proj_revenue )":"572.320000",
              "AVG( proj_gross_profit )":"222.320000",
              "COUNT( pro_num )":2
        },
        {
              "customer_name":"Company2",
              "type_of_shipment":"V",
              "pickup_city":"BUENA PARK",
              "pickup_state":"CA",
              "consignee_city":"NEWARK",
              "consignee_state":"CA",
              "AVG( proj_revenue )":"1132.820000",
              "AVG( proj_gross_profit )":"-217.180000",
              "COUNT( pro_num )":1
        }]
     },
     {
        "customer":"Company3",
        "shipments1":0,
        "profit1":"0.00",
        "gp_percent1":"0.0000",
        "agp1":"0.00",
        "lanes":[
        {
              "customer_name":"Company3",
              "type_of_shipment":"V",
              "pickup_city":"BENSENVILLE",
              "pickup_state":"IL",
              "consignee_city":"STAUNTON",
              "consignee_state":"VA",
              "AVG( proj_revenue )":"3725.000000",
              "AVG( proj_gross_profit )":"1025.000000",
              "COUNT( pro_num )":2
        }]
     }
  ]
```

Any suggestions or available tools for merging JSON objects where two fields are alike and inserting a set of data as a subset?

Answer (score 0):

you probably don't need to think in terms of merge. You would just be looping through one array and adding a property.

You could try something like this:

```
  //build a dictionary so you don't need to do n x m for loops
  var cDataDic = {};

  for(let i=0;i<cData.length;i++){
    if(cDataDic[cData[i].customer_name]){
        cDataDic[cData[i].customer_name].push(cData[i]);
    }else{
        cDataDic[cData[i].customer_name] = [cData[i]];
    }

  }


  //add lanes object
  for(let i=0;i<cData2.length;i++){
      if(cDataDic[cData2[i].customer]){
                cData2[i].lanes = cDataDic[cData2[i].customer]
      }
  }
```

Comment: Only problem I've had with this so far on the test data is that it only grabs the first lane for a customer, not any subsequent lanes. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/514thju6/)

Comment: @NicholasF thanks for commenting - there was a mistake in my logic. I have fixed it now (also updated the http://jsfiddle.net/6w1879vx/)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply filter the cData based on the customer_name and add to the lanes property in the cData2.

```
var mergedData =   cData2.map(data2 => {
   const filterData = cData.filter(cData => {  return cData.customer_name === data2.customer })
   data2.lanes = filterData;
   return data2;
});
```

Hope this helps